# Add Review Information screenshots in apple store?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to add in-app purchase in my ios App "react native".
But in App store should i add screenshots in Review Information sections, 
So what's should i add here?
[image: shot]

and I use `'react-native-iap'`,

when I call `getProducts()` it returns empty array so how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add a screenshot of your paywall that shows the product for review. For testing, you can just upload any image.

Comment: any image? Like what can you share an example, please!

Comment: It needs to be an image of what your paywall looks like, so it would be specific to your app. While you're in sandbox before you submit for review, you can just literally use any image (needs to be the right size) since you may not have a screenshot of your paywall before you develop it.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to test it in sandbox account but in every time i got this error `Cannot connect to iTunes Store` I'm testing it in a simulator because i don't have any real device :(

Comment: Unfortunately you'll need a real device to test purchases on iOS :(

Comment: Hey, Can you check my question again "Edit Section", Please?

Comment: I don't know much at all about `RNIap`, since this seems like a different issue than the original question maybe try asking in a new StackOverflow question.